# reference same cell from multiple sheets

Tags: excel, excel-indirect

I am trying desperately to use the INDIRECT function to pull the values from the same cell on multiple worksheets but all I keep getting is #REF. I have all the sheet names in column I. I tried =INDIRECT(I2&"A1") with I2 being the cell with the sheet name and A1 being the cell on that sheet I want to pull the data for. I'm not sure what's going wrong....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an exlamation mark.

Try =INDIRECT(I2&"!"&"A1")

It works for me.

Comment: Note if the sheet name has a space, i.e. `My Sheet`, you will likely need `=INDIRECT("'"&I2&"'!A1")`.  Also, you don't need to do `"!"&"A1"`, you can just do `"'!A1`.

Comment: =INDIRECT("'"&I4&"'!A1") ended up working. Thanks so much